# Passing variable via onclick event in XSLT doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm new to XSLT & XML. I need to get the value of xml node to send it to the Javascript. I tried to put the value into a variable and send the variable via onclick event. I'm pretty sure Im doing something fishy on passing variable. 
    Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here!

```
<xsl:for-each select="itemCart/items">
         <xsl:if test="iQty>0">
          <tr>
            <xsl:variable name="myId" select="@iId" />
            <td><xsl:value-of select="iId"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="iName"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="iPrice"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="iQty"/></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="iDesc"/></td>
            <td><button type="button" onclick="addItem('myId')" >Add one to cart</button></td>
          </tr>
          </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>

 1. When I alert it it outputs myId
 2. Without quotations it doesn't alert at all
```

Comment: can you provide the XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets and `$` sign to access variable, i.e.:

```
<button type="button" onclick="addItem('{$myId}')">Add one to cart</button>
```